# How can I specify that an Notification action is not shown on Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

If I create an Notification I can add three Actions. Each action can also be invoked on a watch. Is it possible to make some of this actions not available on an Android Wear Watch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you use `addAction()` in `NotificationCompat.WearableExtender`, you are not actually *extending* the actions (despite the name), but rather *separating* them into two lists, one for the phone, and one for the wearable.

- The actions added on the **original** `NotificationCompat.Builder` are shown on the handheld.
- The actions added on the **WearableExtender** are shown on the Android Wear device.

See [Specifying Wearable-only Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#SpecifyWearableOnlyActions):

> If you want the actions available on the wearable to be different from
>   those on the handheld, then use `WearableExtender.addAction()`. Once you
>   add an action with this method, the wearable does not display any
>   other actions added with `NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction()`. That
>   is, only the actions added with `WearableExtender.addAction()` appear on
>   the wearable and they do not appear on the handheld.

Therefore, to have handheld-only actions, add them **before** creating the extender. And To have wearable-only actions, add them **on** the extender. If you use an extender and you want to have repeated actions in both devices, you must add them **in both** (though maybe there is an option to copy them?).

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("The title")
                .setContentText("This is the text")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// Handheld-only actions.
notificationBuilder.addAction(drawable1, "In Both", pendingIntent);
notificationBuilder.addAction(drawable2, "Only in phone", pendingIntent);

// Wearable-only actions.
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
wearableExtender.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(drawable2, "In Both", pendingIntent).build());
wearableExtender.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(drawable3, "Only in wearable", pendingIntent).build());
notificationBuilder.extend(wearableExtender);

// Build and show notification.
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

---

Also

- If you create a `WearableExtender` but don't add any actions into it, then the actions from the original notification are used.
- The "content intent" from the handheld seems to always be present on the watch, with the "Open on Phone" text. I haven't found a way to disable this for the watch only.

Comment: So have you tried to adding an Extender without any actions? Are there no actions set if I add an empty extender? What happens with the content Intent Action is it always present on the watch?

Comment: @Janusz I haven't tested this, but I will later today.

Comment: any update one this ? need to show a notification without any action on android wear